# slim-loading-bar error - Cannot find module '@angular/core'

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular at the moment and I am trying to use the `ng2-slim-loading-bar` but I am getting this error -

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/index.d.ts(1,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/src/slim-loading-bar.component.d.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/src/slim-loading-bar.service.d.ts(1,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs/Observable'.

ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css'
  in [
    /Users/richardwood/Development/Inmate_Intake_App/inmate-intake-app/src
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (/Users/richardwood/Development/Inmate_Intake_App/inmate-intake-app/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13).
```

I am obviously missing something.

I am using Angular 8. 
I installed ng2-slim-load-bar with - `npm install ng2-slim-loading-bar --save`

I also used `npm install rxjs-compat --save`

I then imported the SlimLoadingBarModule inside an app.module.ts file -

```
import { InmateEditComponent } from './inmate-edit/inmate-edit.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { SlimLoadingBarModule } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InmateAddComponent,
    InmateGetComponent,
    InmateEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SlimLoadingBarModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and then included the styling that comes with the library inside src >> styles.css file -

`@import "../node_modules/ng2-slim-loading-bar/style.css";`

and then in the app.component.ts -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SlimLoadingBarService } from 'ng2-slim-loading-bar';
import { NavigationCancel,  
  Event,  
         NavigationEnd,  
         NavigationError,  
         NavigationStart,  
         Router } from '@angular/router'; 


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'inmate-intake-app';

  constructor(private loadingBar: SlimLoadingBarService, private router: Router) {  
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {  
      this.navigationInterceptor(event);  
    });  
  }  

  private navigationInterceptor(event: Event): void {  
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {  
      this.loadingBar.start();  
    }  
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {  
      this.loadingBar.complete();  
    }  
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {  
      this.loadingBar.stop();  
    }  
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {  
      this.loadingBar.stop();  
    }  
  } 
}
```

Would appreciate any help or suggestions if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install on your angular cli.

It will install all missing modules

Comment: Hey Moye Anthonia, thank you for suggesting this. I tried this but I'm still getting the error messages :(

Answer (score 0):

Add  tag in template of your application component.

SlimLoadingBarModule.forRoot()

.forRoot() is important.

Above worked for me.